# SQL: Parse JSON

Tags: sql, arrays, json, parsing

Using SQL, how can I select the value for "conversion_event" from the JSON below?

```
{"str":[1,1342886173,100000627571405,"offsite_conversion.lead",{"action.type":"offsite_conversion","conversion_event":387756207950188,"tag":"lead"},["conversion_event"],[],{"amount":12623486},"1:11:1:0:0:1:0"]}
```

There are some unusual things in here, for example JSON within JSON, and the square brackets. Assume that lengths of all values vary by row, so you cannot slice by a set number of character positions.

Comment: Do you really have to do this in SQL?  Like trying to hammer a nail with a car engine

Comment: There are two which one did you want?

Comment: I've tried to manipulate it using 'LATERAL VIEW JSON_TUPLE' but this sounds like a solution specific to Hive, and not the best way in SQL.

Comment: @Bort unfortunately, I do need to do it using SQL.

Comment: What database are you using?  If this is TSQL you could write a CLR function to do this no problem, I don't know about others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments:

```
declare @astr varchar(max);
declare @start int;
declare @end int;
set @astr = '{"str":[1,1342886173,100000627571405,"offsite_conversion.lead",{"action.type":"offsite_conversion","conversion_event":387756207950188,"tag":"lead"},["conversion_event"],[],{"amount":12623486},"1:11:1:0:0:1:0"]}';

select @start =  charindex('"conversion_event":',@astr)
select @end = charindex(',"tag":',@astr)

select substring(@astr,@start,@end-@start);
```

returns

```
"conversion_event":387756207950188
```

add

```
set @start = @start + 19;
```

to get just the number.

---

```
SELECT substring('{"str":[1,1342886173,100000627571405,"offsite_conversion.lead",{"action.type":"offsite_conversion","conversion_event":387756207950188,"tag":"lead"},["conversion_event"],[],{"amount":12623486},"1:11:1:0:0:1:0"]}',
                  101,16);
```

or

```
select substring('{"str":[1,1342886173,100000627571405,"offsite_conversion.lead",{"action.type":"offsite_conversion","conversion_event":387756207950188,"tag":"lead"},["conversion_event"],[],{"amount":12623486},"1:11:1:0:0:1:0"]}',
                 151,16)
```

---

Ok this is the structure of the object:

```
{
  "str":[1,
         1173,
         10005,
         "offsite_conversion.lead",
         {"action.type":"offsite_conversion",
          "conversion_event":387756207950188,
          "tag":"lead"},
        ["conversion_event"],
        [],
        {"amount":14486},
        "1:11:1:0:0:1:0"
]}
```

An object with an atribute `str` which is an array.

The 5th element has a 2nd attribute conversion event

The 6th element is an array of one element which is conversion event.

So the question is... is this structure the same and which of these do you want?

Comment: Thanks Hogan - but unfortunately the length of many of the values will vary by row, so I cannot use set positions for slicing.

Comment: :P I want the value for the first conversion_event, in this case "387950188".

Comment: So you want `387756207950188`?  And the structure does not change?

Comment: correct. I always want the value that is keyed by the first "conversion_event"

Comment: Good call to just match the strings.